# Check and trigger constraints

Tags: postgresql, trigger, check-constraints, data-integrity

Suppose a DB contains two tables A and B as given below:

```
 A
---------------------
 id        SERIAL
 id_b      INTEGER -- NOT NULL reference to B.id
 ts_update TIMESTAMP

 B
--------------------------
 id             SERIAL
 ts_last_update TIMESTAMP
```

Now let's say that we'd want Postgres to automatically update `ts_last_update` in B such that `B.ts_last_update` is always equal to `MAX(A.ts_update) WHERE A.id_b=B.id` whenever A receives new rows, updates to existing rows or rows are deleted.  Similarly, it would be desirable to ensure that any updates to `ts_last_update` in B conform to the same rule above.

I thought of introducing a trigger that is executed on insert, update and delete operations on A.  But it seems that there'd be a need to also introduce a `CHECK` constraint to `ts_last_update` in B, however this would mean that whenever the trigger in A runs, the check constraint in B would also run which means that **two queries** would be executed.

Is my reasoning above correct or is there a better way of enforcing this strange rule?  Is there perhaps a way of specifying some sort of exclusivity where when the trigger runs, the check constraint is ignored?

Comment: Please lay out what the purpose of the check constraint would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements are not clear in at least three places:

- What should happen if `B` is updated but no related row in `A` is updated? Should `B.ts_last_update` be updated with current timestamp or not?
- What should happen if a row in `B` has 0 related rows in `A` (due to that it was just inserted or the related rows from `A` were deleted? Should `B.ts_last_update` hold the latest update timestamp of B/A rows or be `NULL`?
- I can't see how a `CHECK` constraint would help in your case. `CHECK` constraints are **row constraints**, they can only be used for checking data from one table and each row independently of other rows, not from two tables.

---

If the aim is for that column to always hold the `MAX(A.ts_update) WHERE A.id_b = B.id` value and not to be affected by updates in table `B`, then you don't really need a trigger at all. You can query both tables every time you need the value or have a view:

```
--------------------------
CREATE TABLE B
  ( id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    -- more columns
    -- but no timestamp
  ) ;

---------------------
CREATE TABLE A
  ( id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    id_b      INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES B (id),
    ts_update TIMESTAMP
  ) ;

-- View: B with  ts_last_update
--------------------------
CREATE VIEW BB
    AS
    SELECT B.*,
           ( SELECT MAX(A.ts_update) 
             FROM A
             WHERE A.id_b = B.id
           ) AS ts_last_update
    FROM B ;
```

Comment: I actually have a `CHECK` constraint on the `ts_last_update` attribute that invokes a function that checks that it is either `NULL` (if no rows in `A` exist) or equal to `MAX(A.ts_update)`.  Your suggestion to use a view instead is an interesting one -- thanks!